# Combine cells in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with three rows and three columns. How can I combine the last row columns? My HTML content:

```
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Here I need a cell by all width</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the [`colspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute:

```
<tr><td colspan="3">Here I need a cell by all width</td></tr>
```

> The colspan attribute defines the number of columns a cell should span.

There is a related attribute [`rowspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) that achieves the same for rows.

Comment: As a note: I consider it good practice to link w3.org instead of w3schools as the later are known to make mistakes.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru - Fair point. However, for newbies, I find w3schools to be much easier to understand, and for this kind of information, they are not likely to make a mistake.

Comment: You're arguably right. For these two attributes w3 does a pretty good job explaining them.

Answer (score 8):

For this exact purpose the `colspan` attribute was created.

```
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3">Here I need a cell by all width</td></tr>
</table>
```

Similarly you can use use the `rowspan` attribute if you want to span multiple rows.

```
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td rowspan="3">Spans full table height</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

To learn more about these two attributes visit the official [documentation on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6.1).

**Also I urge you not to use tables unless you need to present tabular data.**