# Fixing a header position for table within container

Tags: css, css-position, containers, fixed

Firstly, I know similar questions have been asked because I have searched through them for days but I have been unable to find a solution that works.

Also, any JQuery/Javascript I try and use simply doesn't affect the table at all for some reason.

Basically I have a table (with a lot of columns) and I want the header within the container but fixed so that if you scroll down within the container the header stays.

I have attempted adding in jQuery, putting the the column names in a different table from the rows, and doing a simple position:fixed and altering the CSS for top and left etc, unfortunately still no luck.

Currently, because im trying to keep this simple I am trying to stick with a CSS solution and my position:fixed is causing this error:

[image]

I've also tried meesing with z-index, but i'm not sure this is relevant to what im trying to achieve

But what it should look like (i've cut out the columns to the side but there are 20+) is this: except that it wont stay fixed within the borders

[image]

My Code:

CSS:

```
    table
{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th
{
    padding: 5px; 
    text-align: right;        
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #555;


}
tbody td
{
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;

}
tbody tr:nth-child(2n)
{
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
tbody tr:hover
{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
td
{
    text-align: right;
}
td:first-child, th:first-child
{
    text-align: left;
}

.table-container
{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative;
    }
```

and my PHP file:

```
    <div class="table-container">
<table>

      <thead>
      <tr>

      <th>Account Name</th>
      <th>Opportunity ID</th>
      <th>Opportunity Name</th>
      <th>Project Manager</th>
      <th>Close Date</th>
      <th>Deal Region</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Post Close Changes</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Racks</th>
      <th>Chassis</th>
      <th>Additional Info</th>
      <th>QA Review</th>
      <th>QA Required</th>
      <th>QA Pack Out Complete</th>
      <th>Material Complete</th>
      <th>Required Build Start</th>
      <th>Actual Start</th>
      <th>Finish Date</th>
      <th>Manufacturing Status</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>LFinish Date</th>
      <th>Power Down</th>
      <th>Ship Date</th>
      <th>Delivery Date</th>
      <th>Requested Delivery</th>
      <th>Altered Requested </th>
      <th>Crating Inspection</th>
      <th>Country Name</th>

      </tr>
</thead>


  <?php foreach ($return as $index => $row) : ?>

    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['Account_Name']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Opportunity_ID']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Opportunity_Name']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Project_Manager']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Close_Date']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Deal_Region']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Status']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Post_Close_Changes']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Product_Name']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Model']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Racks']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Chassis_Count']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['additional_info']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['QA_Review']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['QA_Required']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['QA_Pack_Out_Complete']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Material_Complete']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Req_Build_Start']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Actual_Start']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Finish_Date']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Manufacturing_Status']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Notes']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Start_Date']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['LFinish_Date']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Power_Down']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Ship_Date']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Delivery_Date']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Requested_Delivery']?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['Altered_Requested']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Crating_Inspection']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Country_Name']?></td>

     <td><a href="<?php printf('updateall.php', $row['Opportunity_ID']);?>">Edit</a></td>
     <td>
      <form action="index.php" method="GET">
              <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['Opportunity_ID'];?>" /> 
              <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
      </form></td>

    </tr>

 </tbody>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>

</div>
```

I've been at this for days looking through all sorts of websites and examples, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the reason my Jquery wasn't working was because I am using a virtual machine not connected to the internet and the src="http//.." hence failed. Downloaded the javascript and added it to the folder instead and my issue is now fixed!

(Solution was indeed JQuery)

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is set a class for the row/column(s) your table is on and then try position: fixed. 
I don't know if this works the same for PHP as it does with HTML.

Comment: It's HTML within a PHP file, it's still HTML but i'll give it a go.

Comment: You could also try to lock the first row using the colspan attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477927/html-table-cells-combine

Comment: Or what I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559197/how-to-make-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers-using-css; Seperate the table header from the table.

Comment: Hmm, most of the answers I find are HTML/CSS and do not include interference with PHP. But maybe one of these can help: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/ or http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1080771-Table-body-scroll&p=5459579&viewfull=1#post5459579 ...Else I don't have your answer sadly :<. And I have to wish you good luck!

Comment: It isn't the code type that is the problem, those solutions would work if I had say 3 columns or so, but because I have 20+ i need them encased within the container

Comment: So simply "fixing" the first table row won't work, because you have 20+ columns (horizontal). Which probably means ur screen will get too small eventually.

Comment: Maybe your table is just too big for use in a website? Or if you have less rows than columns, you could switch the columns to be set as rows and viceversa.

Comment: I don't think the table is too big for a website, it's more difficult but it's not impossible to do, if the header isn't fixed it fits fine within a container, it is just important for its purpose that the header is fixed.

Comment: Yes, that much is obvious :). So it is not possible to split your first row (with 20+ columns) and put it into another <DIV> above the table content? This way you can fix the <DIV> and -for instance- create a single table row in this <DIV> and have the table content in a scrollable table.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use **two separate tables**.

```
<table id="tableHeader">
<colgroup>
    <col class="column1"></col>
    <col class="column2"></col>
    <col class="column3"></col>
    <col class="column4"></col>
    <col class="column5"></col>
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
        <th>Header5</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
    </table>
    <div id="tableBody-container">      
<table id="tableBody">
     <colgroup>
        <col class="column1"></col>
        <col class="column2"></col>
        <col class="column3"></col>
        <col class="column4"></col>
        <col class="column5"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Val1</td>
            <td>Val2</td>
            <td>Val3</td>
            <td>Val4</td>
            <td>Val5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val21</td>
            <td>Val22</td>
            <td>Val23</td>
            <td>Val24</td>
            <td>Val25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val31</td>
            <td>Val32</td>
            <td>Val33</td>
            <td>Val34</td>
            <td>Val35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val41</td>
            <td>Val42</td>
            <td>Val43</td>
            <td>Val44</td>
            <td>Val45</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Then you will allow second table container to scroll. But you will need to apply **same column width to both tables**

```
#tableHeader {
    width: 100%;
}

#tableHeader th {
    text-align: left;
}

#tableBody-container {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#tableBody {
    width: 100%;
}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3,
.column4,
.column5 {
    width: 20%
}
```

But there will be one more problem — the scroll of the body will make the body table width less than header table. So a little bit of javascript

```
var scrollWidth = $("#tableHeader").width() - $("#tableBody").width();
$("#tableHeader").css("padding-right", scrollWidth);
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNP3q/

Comment: Problem with this again is that I have 20+ columns, also as I mentioned Javascript doesn't seem to want to work for me when I use it

Comment: Do not quite understand what is the problem with 20+ columns? Could you please describe it more clearly?

Comment: You're fixing the issue by having 5 columns set to 20% width each, I have 20+ columns, the width of each together wouldn't fit onto one page. I believe your solution wouldn't work with that many columns for this reason, I need it within the container.

Comment: So you don't want to set the width value to the columns, you want table default behaviour?